# Is there a way to create this layout using CSS?

Tags: css, css-grid

I have two sections: a hero and an about section. There is a container that I am using but for the about section, the image on the left will go outside of the container line, while the content on the right will stay within the container. I have attached a photo of what I am trying to accomplish.

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#about {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.img img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  display: block;
}

.content {
  background-color: #1A969F;
  padding: 2rem 8rem 2rem 3rem;
}
```

```html
<section id="about">
  <div class="img">
    <img src="about-img.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente, vitae! Quam, ipsam quidem autem numquam ipsa atque debitis similique pariatur aliquid, quibusdam labore mollitia dolorum temporibus et magni, commodi blanditiis.</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

[image]

Comment: yes, with grid you are missing 2 columns.

Comment: So we would use two extra grid columns for the about section? Would we still be able to use the container class for the other sections and navbar?

Comment: i made you an example below of the idea of 2 extra columns (but on the parent ;) ) that #about can span through

Comment: Ah okay, I understand. but how do you set the image to take up one half if there are only three columns?

Comment: the container (`#about`) where stands the image has 2 columns, the **parent** of `#about`  has **3 columns** that `#about` fills all ;)

Comment: ah okay, thank you so much for your help! I truly appreciate it! :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224334/discussion-between-webdev1995-and-g-cyrillus).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from comments:

> yes, with grid you are missing 2 columns. **– G-Cyrillus**

> So we would use two extra grid columns for the about section? Would we still be able to use the container class for the other sections and navbar?  **- Webdev1995**

> i made you an example below of the idea of 2 extra columns (but on the parent ;) ) that `#about` can span through **– G-Cyrillus**

extra column shoul be used from `.container` where you did set the `max-width` inside the `grid` via `minmax()` instead `max-width` on  `.container`.

here is an idea:

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr minmax(auto, 1280px) 1fr
}

section {
  grid-column: 2;
  background: #bee
}

#about {
  grid-column: 1 /span 3;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.img img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  display: block;
  background: #eee
}

.content {
  background-color: #1A969F;
  padding: 2rem 8rem 2rem 3rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <section>whatever of 1280px max-width</section>
  <section id="about">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="about-img.jpg" alt="about illustration">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <h2>Heading</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente, vitae! Quam, ipsam quidem autem numquam ipsa atque debitis similique pariatur aliquid, quibusdam labore mollitia dolorum temporibus et magni, commodi blanditiis.</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>whatever of 1280px max-width</section>
</div>
```